# Liferay copy layout content type across sites

Tags: liferay-7.2

Currently I would like to have ability for copy layout content type from one site to another as draft. But it can't do that with the code below:

```
  private void copyLayout(final Layout srclayout, Layout destLayout) throws Exception {
    Layout destDraftLayout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.fetchLayout(
      PortalUtil.getClassNameId(Layout.class), destLayout.getPlid());
    if (Validator.isNotNull(layout) && Validator.isNotNull(destLayout)) {
      destDraftLayout = layoutCopyHelper.copyLayout(srclayout, destDraftLayout);
      layoutLocalService.updateLayout(destDraftLayout);
    }
```

The content always blank.
Please help, I don't know how to solve this problem.

**Above code working fine with the current site**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution now. I create the new implementation and copy all code from https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/ded0e9390637985231e962e4ad4cfa4639eabb26/modules/apps/layout/layout-impl/src/main/java/com/liferay/layout/internal/util/LayoutCopyHelperImpl.java.

And add this code `newFragmentEntryLink.setGroupId(targetLayout.getGroupId());`

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/ded0e9390637985231e962e4ad4cfa4639eabb26/modules/apps/layout/layout-impl/src/main/java/com/liferay/layout/internal/util/LayoutCopyHelperImpl.java#L237